# sed: remove parentheses from string

Tags: bash, sed

I am using a Mac.

I'm trying to remove all parentheses, ( and ), from a string using sed.

Input: `this string contains (parentheses)`

Desired output:   `this string contains parentheses`

I've tried:

`sed -E 's/[\)\(]//g'`

but whether I escape the parentheses or not, I still only get a match (and consequently removal) for the first one.

EDIT: the problem was with the input string:

A close paren is ASCII 41, whereas my input has ASCII 239 which explains what's failing. Even more confusingly this equates to an acute accent. Closer examination shows that the ) can't be selected without the following 'space'.

Comment: `sed -i '' 's/[()]//g' file` should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104881/remove-particular-characters-from-a-variable-using-bash

Comment: There's something odd about my input string (that I'm getting as output from another source): whatever solution I try, I can't get the closing paren ')' to get picked-up.  I need to look more closely at what the string contains.

Answer (score 2):

[`tr`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html) with the -d (delete) flag is my goto for removing one or more characters. From the man page:

> The tr utility copies the standard input to the standard output with substitution or deletion of selected characters.

```
echo -n 'this string contains (parentheses)' | tr -d '()'
# this string contains parentheses
```

Comment: Thanks. See my comment to the question. Seems there's something strange with input! Your answer works fine if I create the input string from scratch.

Comment: check it out in `hexdump`, it probably isn't an ascii paren

Answer (score 1):

Just DON'T use backslashes (typing `\(` meta-fies the paren) or `-E`xtended pattern matching (which would then require the backslash to UN-meta-fy).

```
$: echo "this string contains (parentheses)" | sed 's/[)(]//g'
this string contains parentheses
```

Comment: Thanks. See my comment to the question. Seems there's something strange with input! Your answer works fine if I create the input string from scratch.

Comment: Within `[]`. nothing has to be escaped, no matter if `-E` is used or not.

Comment: Good point, it's an inherently escaped context, so adding \'s just removes them from the string too.

Comment: What about if you want to use a '[' inside the []?

Comment: `sed 's/[[]//g;'` will do it, but to get `]` you might have to do something like `sed 's/\[//g; s/\]//g;'`